# Unable to get the column of a custom table in the views table using hook_views_data()?

Tags: 7, views

I am writing the following code with hook_views_api() and hook_views_data().
I am able to get the fields of table_in table into list of fields
.But after adding the fields view is not saved and it keeps on loading and preview is not displayed and it keeps on loading

Here table_in is custom table and table_nid is the column of table which has nids matching with node nid.

```
function hook_views_data() {
  $data['table_in']['table']['group'] = t('table_in');

  $data['table_in']['table']['join'] = array(
    'node' => array(
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      'field' => 'table_nid',
    ),
  );

  $data['table_in']['def'] =array(
    'title' => t('def Code'),
    'help' => t('Study def code'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: @ajit I am able to get the base table but when I add the field in existing content type table it keeps on buffering..

Comment: in `$data['table_in']['def'] = `, _def_ is the name of the column of the database. This name should be exactly same as the column name. Other than that your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes its same as column name.

Comment: What about `'field' => 'table_nid',` does that column exist.

Comment: yes this is a column containing nids of a specific content type . the table_nid matches its value with node nid